# Unable to write to Azure Cosmos DB from Databricks

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-databricks

I'm attempting to follow write to Azure Cosmos DB, but failing with the following error:

> flights.write.format("com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark").options(writeConfig).save()
>
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'

I'm using the following document as a guide:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/spark-connector

Can someone let me know where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Please update your question with more details. You only included one line of code. And the doc you pointed to contains a bunch of code snippets, not fully-working examples (though there's a link to full examples in that doc). Without more details, I don't think there's anything that can be done. When you edit your question, you should also include details of the collection you created (and which api you chose), etc.

Comment: flights is not a dataframe.

Comment: @simon_dmorias. You are quite right. Anyhow, I have found the solution, and I'm about to share the solutio in 'Answer Your Question'

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would like to say if that if you follow the documentation I posted it will 100% work.

The reason why if failed for me was because when I originally created the Azure Cosmos DB Account I created with the "Azure Cosmos DB for MongoDB API". I should have created it with the Core (SQL) API and selected Apache Spark Notebook, see image
[image]

After that I used the documentation to connect using Python and it worked first time.

I hope this helps